# Python retrieving data from a block of lines containing specific characters and appending relevant data into separate lines

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program which selects specific information from a bulk paste, extract the relevant information and then proceed to paste said information into lines.

Here is some example data;

```
1.  Track1  03:01
VOC:PersonA 
LYR：LyrcistA
COM：ComposerA
ARR：ArrangerA
ARR：ArrangerB

2.  Track2  04:18
VOC:PersonB
VOC:PersonC
LYR：LyrcistA
LYR：LyrcistC
COM：ComposerA
ARR：ArrangerA
```

I would like to have the output where the relevant data for the Track1 is grouped together in a single line, with semicolon joining identical information and "  -  " seperating between others.

```
LyrcistA  -  ComposerA  -  ArrangerA; ArrangerB
LyrcistA; LyrcistC  -  ComposerA  -  ArrangerA
```

I have not gotten very far despite my best efforts

```
while True:
    YodobashiData = input("")
    SplitData = YodobashiData.splitlines();
```

returns the following

```
['1.  Track1  03:01']
['VOC:PersonA ']
['LYR：LyrcistA']
['COM：ComposerA']
['ARR：ArrangerA']
['ARR：ArrangerB']
[]
['2.  Track2  04:18']
['VOC:PersonB']
['VOC:PersonC']
['LYR：LyrcistA']
['LYR：LyrcistC']
['COM：ComposerA']
['ARR：ArrangerA']
```

Whilst I have all the data now in separate lists, I have no idea how to identify and extract the information from the list I need from the ones I do not.
Also, it seems I need to have the while loop or else it will only return the first list and nothing else.

Comment: I would do: **1** remove empty lines **2** loop read the list, if a line starts with a number, copy all the lines that follow until you read another line that starts with a number into a temporary list **3** sort the temp list **4** loop on the temp list.  Extract the first 3 letters (tag) and what follows the `:` (value) **5** read the next line.  if the current line tag == step 4 tag, output `value form 4; value form current`, else output `value from 4 - value from current`.  **6** flush temp list  **7** next loop on the main list

Comment: Note: if you are sure the order of lines is correct, you might not need to sort the temp list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that doesn't use regular expressions.

- It assumes that header lines, and only the header lines, will always start with a digit, and that the overall structure of header line then credit lines is consistent.  Empty lines are ignored.
- Extraction and formatting of the track data are handled separately, so it's easier to change formats, or use the extracted data in other ways.

```py
import collections
import unicodedata


data_from_question = """\
1.  Track1  03:01
VOC:PersonA
LYR：LyrcistA
COM：ComposerA
ARR：ArrangerA
ARR：ArrangerB

2.  Track2  04:18
VOC:PersonB
VOC:PersonC
LYR：LyrcistA
LYR：LyrcistC
COM：ComposerA
ARR：ArrangerA
"""


def prepare_data(data):
    # The "colons" in the credits lines are actually 
    # "full width colons".  Replace them (and other such characters)
    # with their normal width equivalents.
    # If full normalisation is undesirable then we could return
    # data.replace('\N{FULLWIDTH COLON}', ':')
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', data)


def is_new_track(line):
    return line[0].isdigit()


def parse_track_header(line):
    id_, title, duration = line.split()
    return {'id': id_.rstrip('.'), 'title': title, 'duration': duration}


def get_credit(line):
    credit, _, name = line.partition(':')
    return credit.strip(), name.strip()


def format_track_heading(track):
    return 'id: {id} title: {title} length: {duration}'.format(**track)


def format_credits(track):
    order = ['ARR', 'COM', 'LYR', 'VOC']
    parts = ['; '.join(track[k]) for k in order]
    return ' - '.join(parts)


def get_data():
    # The data is expected to be a multiline string.
    return data_from_question


def parse_data(data):
    track = None
    for line in filter(None, data.splitlines()):
        if is_new_track(line):
            if track:
                yield track
            track = collections.defaultdict(list)
            header_data = parse_track_header(line)
            track.update(header_data)
        else:
            role, name = get_credit(line)
            track[role].append(name)
    yield track


def report(tracks):
    for track in tracks:
        print(format_track_heading(track))
        print(format_credits(track))
        print()


def main():
    data = get_data()
    prepared_data = prepare_data(data)
    tracks = parse_data(prepared_data)
    report(tracks)


main()
```

Output:

```
id: 1 title: Track1 length: 03:01
ArrangerA; ArrangerB - ComposerA - LyrcistA - PersonA

id: 2 title: Track2 length: 04:18
ArrangerA - ComposerA - LyrcistA; LyrcistC - PersonB; PersonC
```

Comment: Any way to make the code accept user input with the data being the ```example data``` in the first box within the question? Would be perfect otherwise

Comment: You mean accept the data as just a single string?

Comment: I guess so, I want the code to be able to just accept a big paste and automatically process the info. Would it also be possible to change the processing of ```non-heading keys in alphabetical order``` to something I can easily change, because the data will include characters like ```作詞, 作曲, 歌と演奏```. After all, I only need the values for composer, arranger and lyricist so even if its hardcoded just to look for those words is OK.

Comment: I can rework in about 10 hours time.  The credit sort is in key order, so by `['ARR', 'COM', 'LYR', 'VOC']` - what order would you like?

Comment: The order you stated is fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I've run into a problem, is there a line I could add to substitute a set value when either one of the credits is missing? eg: ```LYR``` is missing, return the value ```empty``` in its place? Currently if empty value just becomes ```ArrangerA - ComposerA - - PersonA```

Comment: if ```' -  - '``` spotted in credits, insert ```'empty'``` in position. in the ```def format_credits(track)``` But I lack the knowhow to do so, or perhaps you have another solution

Comment: Change the second line of `format_credits` to `parts = ['; '.join(track[k] or ['empty']) for k in order]`.

Comment: any way to implement if no characters found after ```['ARR', 'COM', 'LYR', 'VOC']``` append the next line onto previous line until x happens eg ```COM \n Composer1``` to ```COM: Composer1```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on an answer to your question:

```
data = """
1.  Track1  03:01
VOC:PersonA
LYR：LyrcistA
COM：ComposerA
ARR：ArrangerA
ARR：ArrangerB

2.  Track2  04:18
VOC:PersonB
VOC:PersonC
LYR：LyrcistA
LYR：LyrcistC
COM：ComposerA
ARR：ArrangerA"""

import re
import collections

# Regular expression to pull apart the headline of each entry
headlinePattern = re.compile(r"(\d+)\.\s+(.*?)\s+(\d\d:\d\d)")

def main():
    # break the data into lines
    lines = data.strip().split("\n")

    # while we have more lines...
    while lines:

        # The next line should be a title line
        line = lines.pop(0)
        m = headlinePattern.match(line)
        if not m:
            raise Exception("Unexpected data format")
        id = m.group(1)
        title = m.group(2)
        length = m.group(3)
        people = collections.defaultdict(list)

        # Now read person lines until we hit a blank line or the end of the list
        while lines:
            line = lines.pop(0)
            if not line:
                break
            # Break the line into label and name
            label, name = re.split(r"\W+", line, 1)

            # Add this entry to a map of lists, where the map's keys are the label and the
            # map's values are all the people who had that label
            people[label].append(name)

        # Now we have everything for one entry in the data.  Print everything we got.
        print("id:", id, "title:", title, "length:", length)
        print(" - ".join(["; ".join(person) for person in people.values()]))

        # go on to the next entry...

main()
```

Result:

```
id: 1 title: Track1 length: 03:01
PersonA - LyrcistA - ComposerA - ArrangerA; ArrangerB
id: 2 title: Track2 length: 04:18
PersonB; PersonC - LyrcistA; LyrcistC - ComposerA - ArrangerA
```

You can just comment out the line that prints the headline info if you really just want the line with all of the people on it.  Just replace the built in `data` with `data = input("")` if you want to read the data from a user prompt.

Comment: Your code seems to work the best out of all the solutions given, however, each time I run the code with the same ```data``` the output seems to be in a random or otherwise different order. Is there a way to order the output where it will always return in the format Lyricst - Composer - Arranger?

Comment: Also, if I replace ```data``` with ```data = input("")``` the shell only returns a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in the format you specified in a file called `tracks.txt`, the following code should work:

```
import re

with open('tracks.txt') as fp:
    tracklines = fp.read().splitlines()

def split_tracks(lines):
    track = []
    all_tracks = []
    while True:
        try:
            if lines[0] != '':
                track.append(lines.pop(0))
            else:
                all_tracks.append(track)
                track = []
                lines.pop(0)
        except:
            all_tracks.append(track)
            return all_tracks

def gather_attrs(tracks):
    track_attrs = []
    for track in tracks:
        attrs = {}
        for line in track:
            match = re.match('([A-Z]{3}):', line)
            if match:
                attr = line[:3]
                val = line[4:].strip()
                try:
                    attrs[attr].append(val)
                except KeyError:
                    attrs[attr] = [val]
        track_attrs.append(attrs)
    return track_attrs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tracks = split_tracks(tracklines)
    attrs = gather_attrs(tracks)
    for track in attrs:
        semicolons = map(lambda va: '; '.join(va), track.values())
        hyphens = ' - '.join(semicolons)
        print(hyphens)
```

The only thing you may have to change is the colon characters in your data - some of them are ASCII colons `:` and others are Unicode colons `：`, which will break the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
list_ = data_.split('\n') # here data_ is your data
regObj = re.compile(rf'[A-Za-z]+(:|{chr(65306)})[A-Za-z]+')

l = []
pre = ''
for i in list_:
    if regObj.findall(i):
        if i[:3] != 'VOC':            
            if pre == i[:3]:
                l.append('; ')
            else:
                l.append(' - ')
            l.append(i[4:].strip())
        else:
            l.append(' => ')
        pre = i[:3]

track_list = list(map(lambda item: item.strip(' - '), filter(lambda item: item, ''.join(l).split(' => '))))
print(track_list)
```

**OUTPUT :** list of result you want

```
['LyrcistA - ComposerA - ArrangerA; ArrangerB', 'LyrcistA; LyrcistC - ComposerA - ArrangerA']
```